# combine two gesture raw files in android application

Tags: android, android-ndk, gesture-recognition

I already have a raw file for gesture recognition with me. But I lost the app in android device. So I have to create the app again for gesture builder. But I dont want to lose my previous gestures. There are around 100. Also i have to add a few new gestures. Is there any way of merging both the raw gesture file, the one existing earlier and the one that i created now?

Comment: This is not possible to do as far I know...any one has done it before ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been awhile since you posted this question but I thought I would post my solution to this.

While I was connected to the emulator, I deleted the gesture file that was built by the emulator and then did this command from the command line:
 adb push "yourgesture/file/location mnt/sdcard"

Once I did this I opened the gesture builder on the emulator and clicked reload and all of my existing gestures were there and could be added too.